# How to send true to child when ever i click on parent?

Tags: angular

```
  <vpn-services class="vpn-services" [(callSEntry)]="callSEntry"></vpn-services>
```

On parent i have method:

```
  callSalesEntry() {
            this.callSEntry = true;
        }
```

In child i have this:

```
 ngOnChanges(){
        console.log(this.callSEntry,'aaaa');
}
```

but it fires only once.

Comment: looks correct to me, could you create a plunker? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) can do the trick for you

Though you can use it directly in child component also but using a common service here would be a good practice

First you need to create an emitter in a service something like

```
export class EmitterService {
   public callSEntryEmitter:EventEmitter<boolean>=new EventEmitter(); 

}
```

Then in root component inject service dependency and call change name method to emit the change

```
 constructor(private emitter :EmitterService) {}
 callSalesEntry() {
        this.emitter.callSEntryEmitter.emit(true);
    }
```

And at the end in child component subscribe to changes

```
this.emitter.callSEntryEmitter.subscribe(value=>{do something here})
```

Something like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d42bKafINUqJ1xDQKpXo?p=preview)